# Initiating a RDP session from .net does not work in Windows 10

Tags: vb.net, rdp

The following code that initiates a RDP session works in all versions of Windows except for Windows 10.  Is this a permission issue of some kind?

```
            Dim proc As New ProcessStartInfo
            proc.FileName = "MSTSC.exe"
            proc.Arguments = "/v:" & "testrdp.asuscomm.com:3389”
            Process.Start(proc)
```

After it fails to connect, It displays a standard RDP error: This computer can’t connect to the remote computer. Try connecting again. If the problem continues, contact the owner of the remote computer or your network administrator.

Comment: What exactly isn't working as expected? Do you get an error message?

Comment: How does it not work? Do you get an exception? Also this is VB code so I don't think c# should be tagged.

Comment: It displays a standard RDP error: This computer can’t connect to the remote computer.
Try connecting again.  If the problem continues, contact the owner of the remote computer or your network administrator.

Comment: What happens when you open cmd.exe and type `mstsc.exe /v:testrdp.asuscomm.com:3389`? The code you posted is working fine, it's opening the mstsc.exe process just fine from the sounds of it. A potential issue could be if it's not reading the arguments correctly. Your ending quote is in a different font which is weird (it's showing `”` instead of `"`), so you may have weird characters in the `Arguments` string and is why it's not connecting, e.g., it might be trying to connect to `testrdp.asuscomm.com:3389ᕕ` and obviously `ᕕ` is not a proper port number.

Comment: Sorry about the quotes... I edited the text, that is why they are different, but they are correct in the code (good eyes though!).  I tried what you suggested, and I think you have found the issue... it does not work when I initiate the session manually either, so it has nothing to do with the code.  It is odd because local rdp sessions work fine, but for some reason, Windows 10 does not work with asuscomm.com, but all other versions of Windows do.  If anyone has any idea why, please let me know.  Thank you for your help!

Comment: You could try disabling the firewall completely to see if it's the one blocking the connection.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion... I finally got around to trying it.  It still does not work after disabling the firewall, and there is no other security software on that system.